# how would I calculate how many ping pong balls fit into a cylinder?

Tags: volume

I want to make a lamp made of ping pong balls in a large glass vase and need to calculate the the required amount of ping pong balls

Comment: The least you can do is to give the dimensions of the cylinder and the diameters of the pingpong balls...

Comment: I don't know the dimensions of the cylinder yet. I was hoping for a general formula how to do this with spheres and a cylinder. Ping pong balls have a 40mm diameter

Comment: For an upper bound, the cylinder volume is $V_c=\pi r^2h$ and sphere volume is $V_s=4\pi r^3/3$, so $$n< \frac{\pi r^2h}{4\pi r^3/3}=\frac{3h}{4r}.$$

Comment: @Pixel thank you. I can work with that

Comment: @Pixel Isn't the $r$ in the numerator the radius of the cylinder and the $r$ in the denominator the radius of a ping-pong ball?  I think you've used the same variable for two different things.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, my case example would have a much larger cylinder radius than the ping pong ball radius. Therefore $$n<\frac{pi r^2h}{4\pi r^3/3}$$ is still right though?

Comment: You should use a different letter in the numerator so that $$n<\frac{pi R^2h}{4\pi r^3/3}$$ where $R$ is the radius of the cylinder in mm and $r=20$.  I'm about to type an answer.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @saulspatz yeah that's right, my bad that's a typo which I carried through, the equation should be $$n<\frac{3 R^2h}{4 r^3},$$ since the $\pi$'s cancel. $R$ is the radius of the cylinder and $r$ the sphere.

Comment: "Sphere packing" is an active research subject (try googling with these keywords). You cannot expect simple "formulas" for the maximum number of spheres you can pile up in a special volume like a cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extensive literature on [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing), but I'm not familiar with it.  The section on [irregular packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing#Irregular_packing) in the Wiki article suggests that you won't get a density of more than $64\%$.  That is, the total volume of the ping pong balls will not exceed $64\%$ of the volume of the cylinder.  So if $R,h$ are the radius and height of the cylinder, and $r$ is the radius of a ping pong ball ($r=20$ as I understand it) then$$
.64\frac{3R^2h}{4r^3}=.48\frac{R^2h}{r^3}$$ ought to be enough ping pong balls.